# MySQL server with Nginx

Tags: nginx, mysql

I'm currently running nginx on my server to serve a static website at example.com. I'm using a proxy pass to a node server to serve my api at example.com/api/.

I want to install and run MySQL on that same server. The question is should I just use a proxy pass again to redirect to whatever port MySQL is listening to? Or is there a more appropriate way of running all of these applications in parallel?

Also, if I do use a proxy pass, will I have to specify a certain path to effectively redirect to MySQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install MySQL on that server no problem. It makes no sense to proxy a path on your domain to MySQL, and it makes no sense to ask if you should specify a path when you direct to MySQL. Proxy and redirect are different and distinct things.

You should proxy to an application that uses MySQL.

I think you may need to talk to someone more experienced to work out an approach / solution / architecture for what you're trying to achieve.

**Update**

To allow access to your MySQL instance from your IP address you'll need to allow access through your firewall. On AWS you'd edit your security group to allow access on port 3306 to your IP. I recommend adding a single /32 IP. I open to a wider range because I have a dynamic IP and I'm ok with accepting that risk.

Note that the parts starting "203" and "118" are IP addresses, with parts privacy.

[image]

Comment: So if i were to try to connect to that remote mySQL DB from my windows MySQL workbench, it should work without changing any of the nginx configurations and without proxy passes?

Comment: That's a slightly different situation that you didn't describe in your question. You would typically open the appropriate port(s) in your firewall for your IP address only, and connect to MySQL directly. It might be possible to proxy in Nginx via a TCP type listener, but I can't see any need to do that with what I understand of your situation.

Comment: so, if im using the EC2 instance, should be enough to expose the port in the AWS console?

Comment: You need to create a security group rule that allows access to port 3306 to your IP. I'll edit my question with a screenshot.